# What is the importance of the number nine?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls, skyrim

In the base game (without DLCs):

- There are **nine** [holds in *Skyrim*](https://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Holds).
- There are **nine** [Dragon Priests](https://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dragon_Priest#Dragon_Priests).
- There are **nine** [Divines](https://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Gods_N#Nine_Divines) (if you count Talos).
- There are **nine** [Shadowmarks](https://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Shadowmarks).
- There are **nine** [types of Dragons](https://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dragon#Types).
- There are **nine** [named Dragons](https://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dragon#Named_Dragons).
- **Nine** is a multiple of three, which is the number of words in a [Dragon Shout](https://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Shout).
- Eighteen, the number of [skills](https://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Skills) in the game, is a multiple of **nine**.
- 1,320,969,600 is [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) for 00:00 on 11/11/2011, the release date for *Skyrim*.  This is evenly divisible by **nine**.

Okay, maybe that last three on that list begins to stretch things a bit, but I think the first portion (and probably some others I've not yet realized - if anyone else thinks of any, feel free to edit them into here) are good demonstrations that the number nine seems to have some particular importance in *Skyrim*'s design and culture.  Is there any explanation for this, either in-game or from Bethesda?  Can it be tied to the Norse culture from which much of *Skyrim*'s seems to be derived?

To be clear, I'm not asking for any sort of speculation here.  I figure the answer either lies in some knowledge of Tamrielic or (real-world) Norse mythology with which I am unfamiliar, or it may have been something already addressed by Bethesda separately.  Any answer that cannot provide a solid reference to one of those, in support itself, would be off-topic.

Comment: Related: [23 Enigma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/23_enigma)

Comment: Of course that is what I was referring to, when I included the last three items in my list.  However, I can't see any other number having such apparent significance in the game.  It would seem to me that there is some sort of religious or cultural influence.  Such as the number 7 or 40 in Biblical history.

Comment: Don't forget, November [should also be the 9th month](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Why_is_November_not_the_ninth_month_of_the_year)

Comment: @OrigamiRobot I thought of [The Number 23](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0481369/) while reading this question =)

Comment: Related: [Apophenia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apophenia) and [this TED talk](http://www.ted.com/talks/rives_on_4_a_m.html) :)

Comment: The animal symbols in Nordic Crypts represent ancient Nordic gods, there are nine different animals. There are playable races in Elder Scrolls games, there are 9 cities/counties in Cyrodill, nine original provinces of the empire (each has their own playable race)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to [The Elder Scrolls Wiki](https://web.archive.org/web/20120505061937/http://elderscrolls.wikia.com:80/wiki/Nine_Divines), the origin of the **Nine Divines** (from which many of your mentions are derived) is based on the [Nine Noble Virtues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine_Noble_Virtues) of (real world) Norse mythology:

> The Nine Divines originated from the Nine Noble Virtues of the Norse religion. The Nords of Skyrim are largely based on ancient Scandinavian, or Nordic, cultures here on Earth, and the Nine Noble Virtues played a major role in Norse life.

Bonus numerology:

- Bethesda released **nine** [plug-ins](https://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Official_Plug-ins#Plug-ins) (and one full expansion) to Oblivion.
- Bethesda Softworks' parent company, ZeniMax, also owns the Quake franchise (through id software), for which **Nine Inch Nails** produced music and sound effects

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numbers_in_Norse_mythology 3 and 9 are very important. The shadow mark for danger is suggestive of a 9 point circle.